# Understanding .Net 4.0 features in terms of other technologies

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

I need some document explaining about choosing the .Net over other technologies(web or windows).This is like a kind of compromising the business users for the technology.
Can anyone help me get some documents.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will probably get you started:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302933/asp-net-vs-php-performance-future-proofing-ease-of-development

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at the information on the main [Microsoft .NET Page](http://www.microsoft.com/net).  This includes information for developers (productivity improvements, etc), as well as "Success Stories" which can be used for arguing the business side of this decision.